# Special promotion codes in the Android and IOS apps

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store

I did not find a clear answer to my question in the play and appstore regulations, so I took the liberty of asking the question here.

My app is designed for special marketing events and always aimed at a selected group of users. In order to launch the app you have to enter a special code (Access codes will be created outside of the application and will be sent to the appropriate people on @).

I would like to add the app to google play and the appstore, but I am not sure if the fact that the app is not available to everyone and there will be no information on how to get the code is not against the rules of the shop. Is anyone able to give me a hint on this ?

I did not find a clear answer to my question in the play and appstore regulations, so I took the liberty of asking the question here.

My app is designed for special marketing events and always aimed at a selected group of users. In order to launch the app you have to enter a special code.

I would like to add the app to google play and the appstore, but I am not sure if the fact that the app is not available to everyone and there will be no information on how to get the code is not against the rules of the shop. Is anyone able to give me a hint on this ?